# How do I allow modules to provide their own view?

Tags: 8, views

In Drupal 7, there is `hook_views_default_views()` which allows modules to provide their own views. What's the equivalent for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views are config, so:

1. Create a View
2. Export the config for it as a single item using the UI or drush (removing the uuid if applicable).
3. Include it in your module’s ./config/install folder
4. Install the module on a different site; the View will be created automatically

Comment: but when i use drush to disable the module and then re-enable, it complains that the view is already in the active configuration.

Comment: @liquidcms you can add a dependency on your module to the config file, so the View gets removed when the module is uninstalled. See https://drupal.org/node/2404447

Answer (score 1):

I Have a reference URL for this. Go through, you can achieve this.
Creating views programmatically is quite different than we did in Drupal 7. In Drupal 7 we have hook_views_default_views(), we don’t have this hook in Drupal 8. We will use configuration manager in Drupal 8 for creating views programmatically
[How to create views programmatically in Drupal 8](http://subhojit777.in/create-views-programatically-drupal8/)

Hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*Drupal Console*](https://drupalconsole.com/) to export your views into custom module, e.g.

```
drupal config:export:view viewid --module="modulename"
```

See: [`config:export:view`](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-export-view.html).

> Export a view in YAML format inside a provided module to reuse in other website.

This will export views into module's `config/install` folder which would be imported on install.